# Unable to determine path for background image in Wicket

Tags: css, jetty, wicket-6

I creating a simple web page in Wicket 6.x, which also has a background image.
The landing page, which is `localhost:8080`, has the css defined in the html document as :

```
    <style>
    html,body{
        background: url("bg.png");
    }
    </style>
```

bg.png is stored in src/main/webapp, and seems to work fine.

But once it goes to the next page, in which I have defined the css in the same way, the image does not show. On clicking the generated url, which is `localhost:8080/wicket/bookmarkable/bg.png`, the page says "resource not found".

Where do I keep my css resources and what should be the correct path? Also, is there any method or initialization I need to do in my java class file as well?

Comment: You can set the path on your css inline like this: background: url("/wicket/bookmarkable/bg.png ");. Even if you are in a different URL path will always seek the image.

Comment: url in css are relative to the css. You are using internal css, so modify your path according to your html doc. i.e. it is in root of local host then it will be.. background: url(/wicket/bookmarkable/bg.png);

Comment: It still says 'not found'.
Also, where exactly am I supposed to place this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "/bg.png" as a path. This is context absolute path and will work no matter what is the url of the current page.

Comment: and where do I store bg.png in my system?

Comment: in your-project/src/main/webapp (if you use Maven like folder structure). It should be next to WEB-INF/ folder.